# How to submit the form when pressing Ctrl + S (instead of "save the webpage") in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML page with a form. I don't want to have to move the cursor to and click the "Update" submit button constantly. I want to be able to just press "Ctrl + S" as if it were a text editor, to submit the form (which saves the fields).

No jQuery junk, please.

Comment: We'd like to see what you've tried first. Add your code to your question.

Comment: "_because it can be answered on Stack Overflow_" Greetings to Super User: This question is not answerable as it currently is.